# passing xml using curl with two models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I want to pass this through curl:

```
<invoice>
.....
<invoice-details>
<invoice-detail>
....
</invoice-detail>
<invoice-detail>
....
</invoice-detail>
</invoice_details>
</invoice>
```

I have two models, invoice and invoice_detail, which are associated, by the way. I have a primary key for the invoice to be passed to all the invoice_details so i can id them. for example, if the primary key is 200, i want all the details below that invoice to have a foreign key of 200, too. How am i gonna be able to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml view for this action. In your controller, I suppose you have the following respond_to block:
`respond_to do |format|`
`format.html`
`format.xml {render :xml => @invoice}`

For more on creating xml views, check out xml builder or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936361/how-do-i-use-xml-builder-to-create-xml-in-rails)

To pass it through curl, request the .xml in the url, for example:

`curl "http://yourapp.com/invoices/2/show.xml"`